# SmartGWT vs React.js: a good widget library for the latter?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, widget, smartgwt

We are exploring the feasibility of replacing our current `SmartGWT` app by technologies based on `React.js`.

SmartGWT currently supports a very rich set of widgets.  You can explore the library from their showcase sites:

- [SmartGWT Showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#main)
- [SmartGWT Enterprise Showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#main).

For `React.js`, I have not been able to find an equivalent set of widget library.  I have looked at

- [react-widgets](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/getting-started?_k=cm4r01)
- [Glazier-react-widgets](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/glazier-react-widget)

but they do not seem to be on par with what `SmartGWT` currently offers.

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your application does.

Is it intranet or internet? (SEO, browser usage)

It is a grid-heavy enterprise application?

What is your commitment with SmartGWT (ex: we have 500k lines of code and we can't walk back)?

Would switching UI library cause disruption to your user, would that be an issue?